# Cassandra and cleaning old data with counter type

Tags: select, cassandra, counter, ttl

So I know that TTL is not available for counters because of design reasons and I've read https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-2103 as well as some other SO questions regarding this but there seems to be no clear answer(unless I am missing something which is entirely plausible):

How do we elegantly handle the expiration of counters in Cassandra?

Example use case: page views on a specific day.

For this we might have a table such as

CREATE TABLE pageviews (page varchar, date varchar, views counter, PRIMARY KEY(page, date));

One year from now the information of how many views we had on one specific day is not very relevant (instead we might have aggregated it into a view/month table or similar) and we don't want unnecessary data hanging around in our db for no reason. Normally we would put a TTL on this and let Cassandra handle it for us - elegant! But since we aren't allowed to use TTL for counter tables this is not an option..

You also cant just run delete from pageviews where date > 'xxxx' since both key must be defined in the where clause.
You would first need to query all the page first then issue individual deletes, which is not scalable.
Is there any proper way of achieving this ?

Answer (score 2):

Its ***significantly*** slower, but thats kinda the price if you dont want to manage the expiration yourself - you can use LWTs and actually insert TTL'd columns instead of updating a counter. ie:

```
CREATE TABLE pageviews (
  page varchar,
  date timestamp,
  views int,
  PRIMARY KEY(page, date))
WITH compaction = {'class': 'LeveledCompactionStrategy'};
```

To update a page view:

```
UPDATE pageviews USING TTL 604800
   SET views = *12*
   WHERE page = '/home' AND date = YYYY-MM-DD
   IF views = *11*
```

if it fails, reread and try again. This can be very slow if high contention, but in that case you can do some batching per app, say only flush updates every 10 seconds or something and increment by more than 1 at a time

To see total in range of dates:

```
SELECT sum(views) FROM pageviews WHERE page='/home' and date >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00+0200' AND date <= '2017-01-13 23:59:00+0200'
```

Fastest approach would be to use counters and just have a job during a less busy time that deletes things older than X days.

Another idea if you are Ok with some % error, you can use a single counter per page and use [forward decay](http://dimacs.rutgers.edu/~graham/pubs/papers/fwddecay.pdf) to "expire" (make insignificant) old view increments, will still need a job to adjust landmark periodically though. This will not be as useful for looking at ranges though and will only give you an estimate of "total so far".

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Well, the problem with the job cleaning as I mentioned is that you must know the page id, that mean you have to remember them all. Which in my case can be huge. You can't just do delete from pageviews where date >= 'xxx'. I feel like this is a hard limitation on cassandra and there are legitimate use case where you would want to use ttl and counter rows. After runing some test, select distinct on the primary key is actually quite fast, It just that the amount of delete statements to be issued over a period of time will grow exponentially.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need date range queries, you can use a partition key of `page % X, date` and a clustering key of `page`.

Then for each date you wish to discard, you can delete partitions 0 through X - 1 with X delete statements.